# WPF: How to position a text label on an image as it changes size?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, layout

I have an image inside a grid control, and when I resize the window the image changes its size very nicely, scrupulously preserving its aspect ratio (uniform stretch). If I make the window very tall, the image stays centered and (relatively) small, with whitespace above and below. So far so good.

I am trying to put a small text label in the lower left corner of the image, and I want the label to stay on top of the image, even when there is extra whitespace below. Everything I’ve tried so far positions the text relative to the bottom of the *grid cell itself*, not the (dynamically changing) bottom of the *image*.

I've tried playing with Grid's `auto` and `*`, and I've tried `Canvas`, but I'm stumped. What am I missing? (Note I'm fine with either a XAML or C# solution.)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions> <RowDefinition Height="*"/> </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Path=Bitmap}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
             Opacity="0.85" Text="..." 
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

**Wrong:**

[image: wrong]

**Also wrong:**

[image: also wrong]

**Right:**

[image: right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both `Image` and `TextBox` with another `Grid` and set `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` and `VerticalAlignment="Center"` so that this inner `Grid` will fit to the size of `Image` but not fill the outer `Grid`.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Bitmap}"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Opacity="0.85" Text="..."/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks so much!

("It's easy, when you know how!")